# how to work with multiple viewcontroll and use the viewcontroll.h and m file

Tags: ios

I am new with xcode.
I used one viewcontroller and coded it in the `viewcontriller.h` and `.m` files.

My problem is when I add more viewcontrollers, I can't create more action from the new viewcontrollers to the basic files (`viewcontroller.h` and `.m`).

For example to right click and drag swipe recognizer from new viewcontrollers to the viewcontroller files (h&m files) in interface builder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question to be more clear about what exactly your problem is. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you do want to set the class of the newly added view controllers in interface builder to the class of the view controller you want it to be. Then, you can drag-connect like with the first one, xcode did set up for you initially. Also, do remember to use different view controllers for different purposes (you might have to create another subclass of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment seems to be the answer, I'll add it as an answer:

I suspect you do want to set the class of the newly added view controllers in interface builder to the class of the view controller you want it to be.

Then, you can drag-connect like with the first one, xcode did set up for you initially.

Also, do remember to use different view controllers for different purposes (you might have to create another subclass of `UIViewController`).